# Responsive absolute position to center of DIV

Tags: css

how to make the blue box always displays in the middle of the red box. when I resize the window, the blue box is in a wrong position.
online sample: http://jsfiddle.net/NVjPF/
. Thanks

```
<div id="box1">
    <div id="box2"></div>
</div>

#box1{
display: block;
background:red;
background-size: 100%;
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 60%;
}

#box2{
    display:block;
    background:blue;
    position:absolute;
    height:70px;
    width:70px;
    right:50%;
    top:50%;
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated by the others, you need to add

```
margin:-35px -35px 0 0;
```

for the box to be centered correctly. It doesn't matter what the screen size is, it will never be truly centered to the middle of the box. The reason for this is because the browser is taking the upper right corner of the box, and putting that in the middle of the box. So in some sense, the box is centered. If you were to have the box set to `left:50%;` instead of `right:50%;`, then the box would be centered by the upper left hand corner. So to fix this problem, you take half the width and height, because that will equal the center of the box.

Also, to account for the box breaking out of the red box, I added `overflow:auto;` to create the scrollbars when needed. If you don't want the scrollbars, then you can change it to `overflow:hidden`. Either one will work if you don't want any protrusion.

http://jsfiddle.net/burn123/NVjPF/3/

Comment: This is the best answer I've ever met.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use negative margins to account for the difference.  In this case, you can add:

```
margin-right: -35px;
margin-top: -35px;
```

The `35px` stems from half of the size of the inner element.  See http://jsfiddle.net/NVjPF/1/ for the live demo.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.  Basically, you move the box half way over inside the parent and then bring it back dead center using negative margins equal to half of the box's width and height.

```
#box2 {
display:block;
background:blue;
position:absolute;
height:70px;
width:70px;
right:50%;
top:50%;
margin:-35px -35px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try that, works well for me:

```
#box2 {transform: translate(-50%, 0%);}
```